# Input Stream getting filled with null data

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream

So I am creating a server that I am trying to get to handle ASCII data. While I can get the Streams to work and call the methods. However the listening thread to add items to a Queue (`ArrayBlockingQueue`), and it will loop until the queue is full with null data.

Server code, Client Handler (compressed, let me know if I left something out.):

```
class ClientThread extends Thread {

  // ASCII commands defined here (byte NUL=0x00; byte SOH=0x01; etc.) 

  private Socket socket;
  private InputStream sInput;
  private OutputStream sOutput;

  BlockingQueue<byte[]> queueIn = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(30, true);

  private boolean goodToGo = false;

  ClientThread(Socket socket){

    id = ++Server.uniqueId; /* To be replaced with UIDs */
    this.socket = socket;

    /* Create Data Streams */
    try {
        sInput = (socket.getInputStream());
        sOutput= (socket.getOutputStream());
        goodToGo = true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ServerInit.logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Error Openning Streams!", ex);
    } 
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    boolean keepGoing = true;

    System.out.println("Client thread started.");
    /* Start listening thread */
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(goodToGo) {
                System.out.println("Listening thread looping.");
                try {
                    byte[] temp = IOUtils.toByteArray(sInput); // read client input using Apache Commons IO.
                    // Add the result to the queue.
                    queueIn.put(temp);
                } catch (EOFException eof){
                    ServerInit.logger.log(Level.INFO,"Remote client closed connection.");
                    close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    ServerInit.logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Error Reading Stream!", ex);
                    close();
                } 
            }
        }
    }.start();

     while (keepGoing && goodToGo){
        System.out.println("Main thread looping.");
        try{

            byte[] message = queueIn.take();

            if (message.length >= 4){

               /* Message picked apart and worked with here */

            } else if (message.length == 0 ){
                // Do nothing.
            } else {
                ServerInit.logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to process item from queue.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* Here just for completeness, I don't catch Exceptions this way. :) */
        }
     }
   }

   protected void close(){
    // try to close the conection
    goodToGo = false;
    try {
        if (sOutput != null) {
            sOutput.close();
        }
        if (sInput  != null) {
            sInput.close();
        }
        if (socket  != null) {
            socket.close();
        }

        ServerInit.SERVER.remove(id);

    } catch (Exception e){
        ServerInit.logger.log(Level.FINER, "Error closing client connections.", e);
    }
  }
}
```

And client code:

```
public class TestClient{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
      Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5525);
      OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
      byte[] buffer = { 0x02, 0x05, 0x07, 0x04 };

      outputStream.write(buffer);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       /* Again, I don't catch exceptions like normally. */
    }
  }
}
```

***My Questions:* What is causing the "listening" thread to loop and add null data to queue indefinitely?**

And While I know this is not the **Code Review** exchange, if anyone can think of better classes to utilize, If they could just mention it.

**EDIT:**

Following a suggestion, I changed the queue from an `ArrayList<>` to an `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: @JJF from what I read, Input streams should block until data is available. (The Apache commons is using the read method to create the byte array.) I will take a look at the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IOUtils.toByteArray()` is not appropriate for this usage. It will read to end of stream  and return you one big byte array, not a sequence of messages. So there is certainly no point in calling it twice, or in a loop. After the initial result, all you can get is an infinity of empty byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `IOUtils.toByteArray` but my suspicion is that if there is no data in the stream when you call it then it either returns null or an empty array.

This makes sense if you think about it since otherwise it has no idea how many bytes to read. It has no way to know if you are sending an array containing 1, 4 or 1000 bytes so it just reads everything that is ready when you call it.

You need to somehow sleep between each call to `toByteArray` and ignore any empty responses. A better way would be to see if you can sleep until more data arrives on the socket.

Comment: have used the read method for `InputStream.read(byte[] message)`, and Received the same results. The `IOUtils.toByteArray` is simply a mask of the `read()` Stream method, So I believe this is not the porblem.

Comment: It reads to end of stream, not 'everything that is ready when you call  it'. @Gamerb it is not 'simply, a mask for the `read()` method'. If it was there would be little point in using it.